# How to change head title name of nuxt.js web app using by json data?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js

I want to change head title of my latest project web app that used nuxt.js.
I used json data to change head title but it doesn't work.
My json file is placed in static direcotory like "~/static/images/head.json".

[image]

In head.json, like

```
{
  "head": "sample head"
}
```

and I changed head object in nuxt.config.ts file like below.

```
import head from "~/static/images/head.json";
export default {
 head: {
    titleTemplate: head.head,
    ～～～～～
  },

}
```

and run my web app and file reference error occurred like below.
[image]

I don't know why that error occurred.
In nuxt.config.ts, import reference seems no problem.
Does anyone advise me how to use json file data as head title information?

---

This is [my Github sample link.](https://github.com/takopon2525/nuxttestsample)

Comment: What if you try `@/static/images/head.json`?

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have a Github repo for this?

Comment: sure! I gonna make a Github repo. please give me a few minutes.

Comment: https://github.com/takopon2525/nuxttestsample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

- I've cloned [your repo](https://github.com/takopon2525/nuxttestsample)
- updated the path with `import head from './src/static/images/head.json'`
- ran a `yarn build && yarn start`
- enjoyed a working meta-tag!

[image]